# Disk is almost full on a server with CPanel

Tags: linux, partition, system-installation, disk-usage, size

I have VHM system and I have a domain and two subdomain on this system. I tried to take a backup than after sometime I cannot access cpanel but I can access VHM. but some of the VHM options gives disk space error. which is:

> The filesystem mounted at / on this server is running out of disk space. cPanel operations have been temporarily suspended to prevent something bad from happening. Please ask your system admin to remove any files not in use on that partition.

On VHM the disk information as follow:

Disk information

```
Device  Mount point Usage   
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-home   /home   30% (126,759,988 of 458,391,760)
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-root   /       100% (19,593,632 of 20,642,428)   
/usr/tmpDSK                   /tmp    3% (10,601 of 495,844)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It always annoys how CentOS/RHEL, by default, on a large hard disk, create a fairly small `/` partition and a really huge `/home` partition.  This is why, when install CentOS, I always manually partition, and never use LVM (which, I have heard, also reduces performance).  LVM makes sense when you want to stream a partition across multiple hard disks, but not as much sense when there is only one hard disk.

To answer the original poster, log in to a Linux shell.  Then, as root:

```
du -ax / > /home/rootfl
sort -n /home/rootfl | tail -30
```

This will show which files and folders on the root partition are taking up so much space.  For example, let us suppose that it is /var/www that is taking the majority of the space:

```
cp -a /var/www/ /home/www-home/
cd /var/
rm -fr www # CAREFUL, DANGEROUS COMMAND!
ln -s /home/www-home/ www
```

We are

- Copying all the files from `/var/www` to `/home/www-home`
- Removing the space-eating `/var/www/` directory
- Making a symbolic link, so that these space eating files are now on the `/home` partition

Comment: The large home is typical of cPanel servers, which store all websites and user data there. The performance reduction from LVM is *very* small (except when creating snapshots). LVM also makes sense when you want snapshot features, or have the *option* to add more space to partition by adding another drive later. I see very little reason not use it.

Comment: thanks a lot. I deleted so many unwanted files now I'm okay. I'm going to ask to server provider to increase the harddisk for me. thanks.

Comment: Large `/home` is the default in CentOS 6; you have to go out of your way to manually partition things to not have one.  I had to reinstall CentOS this week because it gave me a large `/home`, which is next to useless for an OpenVZ host.